# retrieve updated array list from jsp to action class in struts2

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, struts2

I am retrieving database values and putting them in an array list(al). This array list is getting displayed in a JSP page in the form of a table. I want to modify the values in JSP page and update the new value in the database using Struts2. How do i do that?

Main action class

```
public class HelloWorldAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{
ProjectDb pd;
public ProjectDb getPd() {
    return pd;
}

public void setPd(ProjectDb pd) {
    this.pd = pd;
}
ArrayList<ProjectDb> al=new ArrayList<ProjectDb>();
public ArrayList<ProjectDb> getAl() {

    return al;
}

public String status() throws Exception{
    boolean flag=false;


    try{
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

        Connection conn = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:\\Db1.mdb");

        username=(String) map.get("user");
        PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(  
                "SELECT * FROM StaleInGers WHERE (((StaleInGers.mailId)=(Select email from DBA where username='"+username+"' and email='"+email+"')))");  
        //ps.setString(1,username);  
        //ps.setString(2,password);  

        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();  

        al=new ArrayList<ProjectDb>();
        while(rs.next()){
            pd =new ProjectDb();
            pd.setProject(rs.getString("project"));
            pd.setStatus(rs.getString("status"));
            pd.setComments(rs.getString("comments")); 

            al.add(pd);


            flag=true;
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception : " +e);
    }  
    if(flag==true){
        return "success";
    }
    else{
        return "error";
    }       
   }
}
```

This is POJO class

```
public class ProjectDb {
private String project,status,comments,email;

public String getEmail() {
return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
 }

public String getProject() {
return project;
}

public void setProject(String project) {
this.project = project;
}

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

public String getComments() {
return comments;
}

public void setComments(String comments) {
this.comments = comments;
}
}
```

This is the JSP page where i display the array list

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4 
/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table,td,th {
border: 1px solid green;
width:100%;
}

th {
background-color: green;
color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="update">
<table >
<tr>
<th>Project</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Comments</th>
</tr>
<s:iterator value="al" id="array" status="alStatus">
<tr>
<td><s:property value="%{project}"/></td> 
<td><s:textfield name="array[%{#alStatus.index}].status" value="%{status}" theme="simple" 
/></td>
<td><s:textfield name="array[%{#alStatus.index}].comments" value="%{comments}" theme="simple" 
/></td>
   </tr>
   </s:iterator>
    </table><br><br>
    <input style="opacity: 0.7; border-radius: 5px; border: 0; width: 250px;   
       height:35px;          
       font-family: Goudy Old Style; font-size: 22px; background: #00CC80;"
       type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>             
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can do it in many ways, do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 1):

The first that comes in mind is making the table fields of input type, and place the values that come from ArrayList on each input value paramether. After this make an update method (like satus() one), and using your pojo's setters update the input values triggering the update method on form action.

It should look something like this:

Update method in HelloWorldAction:

```
public void update(ProjectDB prjDb) throws Exception{
boolean flag=false;
PreparedStatement ps = null;


try{
    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

    Connection conn = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:\\Db1.mdb");

    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    username=(String) map.get("user");
    /*Selecting which field would be updated */
    if(!"".equals(prjDb.getEmail().trim())){
     ps=conn.prepareStatement(  
            "UPDATE StaleInGers SET email=?  WHERE (((StaleInGers.mailId)=(Select email from DBA where username='"+username+"' and email='"+email+"')))");  
     ps.setString(1,prjDb.getEmail());
    }
    //else if(...){...} --> Treat all the cases, if email is not empty, and another field is not empty, if only one field is not empty, etc..


    int i = ps.executeUpdate();
    conn.commit();  




        if(i>0){ flag=true; }
    }


} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception : " +e);
}  
if(flag==true){
    return "success";
}
else{
    return "error";
}       
}
//Don't forget to close the connection and prepared statement
```

The fields must be populated from the array on action that gets you into this page (there you can make the updates) as you did in your JSP. This is the Demo example of the update method but it should work, i let you wrote the rest of the code by yourself.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit ?I am new to Java,however, i did try to retrieve the values using getters and setters but i am getting nothing..

Comment: Check this tutorial for more details: http://www.java4s.com/struts-tutorials/struts2-insertupdatedeleteoperations-through-jdbc-real-time-application/

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `var` instead of `id` (that is deprecated) in the Iterator; in your case, it is not even needed BTW.
2. Ensure in your target action (`update`) you have a `List<ProjectDb>` (use the Interface List, not the implementation ArrayList) named `array`, with getter/setter;
3. use an `<input type="hidden" />` to send the value that you are showing with `<s:property />`:

   ```xml
   <td>
       <s:hidden name="array[%{#alStatus.index}].project" value="%{project}" />
       <s:property value="%{project}" />
   </td>
   ```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what i should do in action class further?? I did try your suggestion,but i am not getting any values from jsp..

Comment: The `name` attribute is used to map the target property in the target action. If you write `name="foo[0].project"`, you need in the `update` action (targeted by your form) `private List<ProjectDb> foo;`. If you write `name="foo.project"`, you need `private ProjectDb foo;`. If you write `array[%{#alStatus.index}].project`, you need `private List<ProjectDb> array;`. Don't forget the setter ;)

Comment: Nice avatar, Calvin & Hobbes FTW 8)

Answer (score 0):

Previously I need to pass javascript array to action class of struts 2, i tried with json, `var arr1=["1", "2", "3"],` in

```
$.getJSON('ajaxSaveDetails', {
          javaArray : JSON.stringify(arr1)
          }.fail(function(){
              $(".error-txt").text("Error occured");
    });
```

In Action class, i written `private String javaArray ;` and in method

```
jsonArray = (JSONArray)new JSONParser().parse(javaArray);
```

I got proper array.